# Объекты проходят сквозь объекты при перемещении предметов курсором в Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, объекты, mouse-event

Подскажите в чем может быть ошибка - при перемещении предметов курсором, они проходят один через другой. Ниже прилагаю код, который я использую:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{

    offset = gameObject.transform.position -
        Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 10.0f));
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 10.0f);
    transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(newPosition) + offset;
}
```

Когда я перетаскиваю объект во время игры, объект проходит через другие объекты, если его бросить, он отскакивает от объектов и не проваливается. На объектах, которые можно перетаскивать, у меня стоят Rigidbody2D и Box Collider 2D, а на статичных объектах, например на полу, стоит только Box Collider 2D. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки нет, какую координату ты указал, туда он и перемещается. Иначе быть с `transform` не может.

А столкновение это уже вопрос физики и перемещать нужно по физике, а не "телепортацией". Тут либо предмет должен тянуться в направлении курсора через `AddForce`, либо создать упругую резинку между объектом и курсором через `Join`.